# what kind of laser is this?

Tags: laser

This is a 40mW laser. It's about 2 inches long.

What kind of laser is it (diode, etc?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sure looks like a diode laser. Where did you get it? What color does it produce?

Comment: how do you know that its output power is 40 mW?

Comment: It's a 532nm (green) laser from a raman spectrometer. The manufacturer said it was 40mw. Why, doesn't it look like a 40mw laser but higher power?

Comment: Maybe an IR-laser diode pumped (DPSS) laser. Was/is it temperature-controlled?

Comment: What do you mean temperature controlled?

Comment: Say, is the DPSS above available new or can be bought like it or is it assembled further by the integrator? What particular brand is it? Any url?

Answer (score 4):

532nm says DPSS (Diode pumped solid state) with intracavity doubler.

It is really two lasers, an 808nm diode laser that provides optical pump power to drive a Nd-YAG laser crystal that operates at 1064nm. Within the YAG laser cavity is a non linear element that generates the output light by frequency doubling the 1064nm radiation to get to 532nm.
I would expect the pump laser to be a few hundred mW or so to get 40mW of green.

Be careful, 40mW does not sound like much, but given the application it might have quite good beam quality (And may even be passively Q switched) in which case that is quite sufficient to cost you (or someone nearby) an eye. 
DPSS lasers also sometimes leak significant amounts of infra red along an axis that is not necessarily aligned with the main beam.

Comment: Say. Do commercial NOHD (Nominal Ocular Hazard Distance) values already taken into account this leaking of significant amounts of infra red along an axis that is not necessarily aligned with the main beam?? Arent there DPSS laser where all this leakages were already filtered inside the laser?

Comment: Of course there are DPSS lasers that are well filtered, but without knowing the optical design (or reading the device spec sheet) how would you know if this is one of them? Sometimes the CDRH labelling will give you a clue, but with the junk out there these days I would never assume. The NOHD data is usually calculated per wavelength, but again better to do an actual calculation for your specific use case. That is clearly a module intended for integration into a product,and the certifications apply to the product not the module....

Comment: What device can you use to measure the leaking infra red and its intensity of any DPSS laser?